# How can I align divs correctly to fit page width without overflow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Okay so I am playing around with flex box, I have created this simple layout of divs but I am evidently formatting them wrong. 
I have put a div at the top for 100% so you can compare where the divs end.

[image: Ideal Situation]

Is there a way to align the divs to fit the page?

I thought that simply adding some % width statements I could easily fill the page however since I'm using margins for the divs it doesn't add up. See [codepen here](https://codepen.io/shayrapet/pen/bZydLX) and snippet below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.myBox {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.headerTitle {
  width: 100%;
}

.bottomLeft {
  width: 29%;
}

.bottomRight {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapBottomRight {
  width: 37%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myBox headerTitle">
    <h1> HELLO THERE </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Some shit </p>
  </div>
  <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Some shit </p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapBottomRight">
    <div class="myBox bottomRight">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
    </div>
    <div class="myBox bottomRight">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a *wrapping flexbox* all factors that contributes to the width of the *flex items* relative to the flexbox must be considered - so margins and borders must be taken into account:

- remove default `body` margin
- use `border-box` to include `padding` and `border` in `width`
- Use `width: calc(33.33% - 10px)` for the `mybox` and `wrapBottomRight` elements

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.myBox {
  width: calc(33.33% - 10px); /* added*/
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.headerTitle {
  width: 100%;
}

.bottomLeft {
  /* width: 29%; */
}

.bottomRight {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapBottomRight {
  width: calc(33.33% - 10px); /* added */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myBox headerTitle">
    <h1> HELLO THERE </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Some shit </p>
  </div>
  <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Some shit </p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapBottomRight">
    <div class="myBox bottomRight">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
    </div>
    <div class="myBox bottomRight">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you will likely want to tweak the widths and heights of the different divs, but the layout you are after is quite easy with flexbox and `justify-content: space-between;`. In order to achieve this I needed to add one more wrapper `.bottomContainer` and remove the `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Check out the `flex-direction: column:` where you need boxes to flow vertically.

Everyone's favorite flexbox resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 5px;
}

.bottomContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.myBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.headerTitle {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bottomLeft {
  width: 30%;
}

.bottomRight {
  height: 48%;
}

.wrapBottomRight {
  width: 37%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myBox headerTitle">
    <h1> HELLO THERE </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottomContainer">
    <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
    </div>
    <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapBottomRight">
      <div class="myBox bottomRight">
        <h2> Title </h2>
        <p> Some shit </p>
      </div>
      <div class="myBox bottomRight">
        <h2> Title </h2>
        <p> Some shit </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.myBox {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%
}

.headerTitle {
  width: 100%;
}

.bottomLeft {
  width: 20%;
}

.bottomRight {
  width: 20%;
}

.wrapBottomRight {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myBox headerTitle">
    <h1> HELLO THERE </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Some shit </p>
  </div>
  <div class="myBox bottomLeft">
    <h2> Title </h2>
    <p> Some shit </p>
  </div>
    <div class="myBox bottomRight">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
    </div>
    <div class="myBox bottomRight">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p> Some shit </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Happy Coding!